# How do I prove that $a\in (\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})^2 \Leftrightarrow a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1 \pmod p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

$p$ is prime number $>2$ and $a$ is a square.   $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*} $ is a cyclic group.

I need to show that $$ a\in (\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})^2 \iff a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1 \pmod p $$

Any ideas how?

I need to prove two directions...

Thank you!

**Q: Have you any idea how do I prove this direction? $\Longleftarrow$**
(I understand the other direction, but please help me with this one...)

Comment: $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = ?$

Comment: Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem ?

Comment: Because they are both equivalent to $a$ not being a multiple of $p$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan - I try to use this theorem, but I didn't understand how it's help me...

Comment: @AshGX - So, how it's prove it? I need to get 2 directions...

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10904/let-a-be-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-prove-ap-1-2-equiv-1-bmod-p). This is a direct consequence of [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Euler%27s_criterion).

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=b^2$$$a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = ({b^2})^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = b^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$$

Comment: Why should $a$ be a square modulo $p$?

Comment: Because that's what is given.

Comment: This is one direction, how I prove the other one?
Thank you!

Comment: @Stefan Oh, I see!

Comment: At the second direction we have to use that this is a cyclic group...

Comment: @YoavFridman: If $a^{(p-1)/2} = 1$, then $a^{(p-1)/2 - 1} \times a = 1$. Remember the definition of a unit.

Comment: @nik, OK, and what I'm doing next?? Thank you!

Comment: @nik, I didn't understand how what you write helps me...
Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman: if there exists an element $b$ such that $ab \cong 1 \pmod{p}$, can you prove that $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$? I just gave you $b$.

Comment: But I didn't understand how does it help me to prove that $a$ is a square...

Comment: @YoavFridman: Don't you assume that $a$ is a square from the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

By little Fermat, we know that for any $a\neq 0$ in $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ we have $a^{p-1}=1$. This means that $a^{\frac{p-1}2}=\pm 1$. It is a theorem that in $\Bbb Z_p^{\times}$, exactly half of the elements are squares (namely, those that correspond to $1^2,2^2,\ldots,\left(\frac{p-1}2\right)^2$) and half are non-squares. But by Lagrange's theorem, $a^{\frac{p-1}2}=1$ has at most $\dfrac{p-1}2$ solutions and by the previous claim at least $\dfrac{p-1}2$ solutions. Thus, it has exactly $\dfrac{p-1}2$ solutions, the squares $\mod p$. Thus if $a=b^2$ the equations holds, and if $a$ is not a square the equation doesn't.

**ADD** Using $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ is cyclic. Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. We can write $a=g^k$ for some $k$. By $g^{k(p-1)/2}=1$, it follows that ${\rm ord}(g)=p-1\mid (p-1)k/2$. This gives $k/2$ is an integer, so $k=2m$, and $a=g^{2m}=g'^2$ where $g'=g^m$.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use L. theorem...

Comment: @YoavFridman What prevents you from using it? It is true in general for any field, and the proof is straightforward.

Comment: We don't learn it at the class...
Can you help me please with this direction <=??

Comment: @YoavFridman I have added something.

Comment: Thank you, but how does it prove what I want?
Why $g^{k(p-1)/2}=1$?
How do you know this?

Comment: You have that $a^{(p-1)/2}=1$. Substitute.

Comment: And why this is prove that $a$ is a square??

Comment: @YoavFridman Did you read what I have added? Read it carefully.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain me one more thing: ${\rm ord}(g)=p-1\mid (p-1)k/2$. This gives $k/2$ is an integer...
Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman Think about it a little more. What does it mean that $p-1\mid (p-1)k/2$? Write it out, and conclude that $k/2$ must be an integer.